# Math Operators and beamer

Tags: beamer, xetex, math-operators, unicode-math

I'm using xelatex and I'm having a very strange problem:

while

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}                                            
\usepackage{amsfonts}                                          
\usepackage{amssymb}                                            
\usepackage{amsthm}                                             
\usepackage{unicode-math} 
\begin{document}
  $$
  \sin(x)
  $$
\end{document}
```

is working perfectly:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}                                            
\usepackage{amsfonts}                                          
\usepackage{amssymb}                                            
\usepackage{amsthm}                                             
\usepackage{unicode-math} 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  $$
  \sin(x)
  $$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

doesn't dislay the "sin". It looks completely blank. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internally, `beamer` replaces certain fonts. Apparently the you don't have the replacement font in a place where XeLaTeX can find it, so it doesn't appear. To suppress this replacement, you can either load the `beamer` class with the `professionalfont` option, or add `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` to your preamble. (Note the difference!)
See section 18.1 of the `beamer` documentation for details.

Also, see [Why is [ … ] preferable to $$ … $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/24974)

```
\documentclass[professionalfont]{beamer}
%\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}                                            
\usepackage{amsfonts}                                          
\usepackage{amssymb}                                            
\usepackage{amsthm}                                             
\usepackage{unicode-math} 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \[
  \sin(x)
  \]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]